# Remove grids from colored images

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

There are colored images which have grids present on them and we need to remove the grids from the image without affecting the features of image.
We have tried Canny edge detection, Sobel filters, Mid point filter, Median filter, Bitwise filter,Denoising filers, etc and almost every possible things we have tried but we are not able to get the appropriate answers, our image gets blurred and the grids are not able to remove from the images, and the important parts and the useful features of the images get erode away.

We want to remove the grids without affecting the features(without blurring) of the image.

[image]

We have provided the image link below.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=14qKZv7pOeN6QbVmxZyk_TUu2usOekoWQ

Comment: Your image is of rather low quality. Are you able to provide a higher quality, preferably PNG format image please?

Comment: Sorry sir image quality is as it is , there is no change in the quality of the image.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to play a little bit with your image, but its resolution and quality are quite poor, so the results are not optimal(if you can try to upload an uncompressed image and I'll do a double check on it)...
In any case I think the idea is there:

```
    img = cv.imread(path_to_img)
    gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    #use any good value that extract the grid, 15 should be good enough
    res, mask = cv.threshold(gray, 15, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV) 

    #just to better highlight the mask
    kernel = np.ones((3,3), np.uint8)
    dilation_image = cv.dilate(mask, kernel, iterations=2)

    dst = cv.inpaint(img, dilation_image, 15, cv.INPAINT_TELEA)
    #dst = cv.medianBlur(dst, 5) #optional, to check if needed
    cv.imshow("output", dst)
```

Reference for inpaint method:
https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/df/d3d/tutorial_py_inpainting.html

Comment: Your code remove the background not grid. I want remove grid

Comment: The grid and the background, at a first glance, seem both black so the filtering should work as is, but, as I said in my answer, due to the poor quality of your image, the grid is not well defined: the compression blurred and mixed it with your features. In my opinion, first of all you need to find a better photo.

Answer (score 0):

use threshold or other tools to find that grid and word. if the grid appears at fix location, you can just create a mask image by hand. Then use the impaint to remove it

[image]

```
img = cv2.imread('you_scan.png')
mask = cv2.threshold(img, 210, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1][:,:,0] # if threshold can not achieve, use other tools for fixd position grid mask.
dst = cv2.inpaint(img, mask, 7, cv2.INPAINT_NS)
```

Comment: please use our image which is specified in the link below to remove the grids from the image